# AJAX mvc web api: create div with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I am working with restful API, MVC and ajax. I am trying to get data from the backend and then display images inside some divs. The result should be the following:
[image]

This is my backend code:

```
  /*route:api/images*/
  [HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<DTO> GetData(string Id) {
        /*Do something*/
        return Dto;/*the dto has an imgurl property*/           
    }
```

In my front end

```
<div id="mydiv></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:59245/api/api/images",
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {                 
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                    $('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="thumbnail">'+
            '<h3 class="centrar">' + data[i].Titulo + '</h3><a href="'+
            data[i].ImagenUrl+'</a><p>'+data[i].Paragraph+'</p></div>'
            ).appendTo("#mydiv");
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that when I try to display the images inside #mydiv, this is the result:
[image: result of the ajax code]

We can see in  that the anchor tag is wrapping the paragraph but in my ajax code I did not mean to do this.
How do I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have the img tag. Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:59245/api/api/images",
        type: "Get",
        success: function (data) {                 
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                $('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="thumbnail">'+
        '<h3 class="centrar">' + data[i].Titulo + '</h3><a href="'+
        data[i].ImagenUrl+'"><img src="'+data[i].ImagenUrl+'"/></a><p>'+data[i].Paragraph+'</p></div>'
        ).appendTo("#mydiv");
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a typo here - the `<a>` tag is not closed:

```
$('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="thumbnail">'+
        '<h3 class="centrar">' + data[i].Titulo + '</h3><a href="'+
        data[i].ImagenUrl+'"><img src="'+
        data[i].ImagenUrl+'"></a></div>'
        ).appendTo("#mydiv");
```

This will output the image and make it into a link. I am guessing you will have to mark it up to get the result that you posted.